# Erro ao incrementar valor em inputs com mesma classe?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho uma função que cria um loop de inputs dependendo da quantidade de parcelas inseridas pelo usuário e ao inserir um valor no primeiro ele incrementa em 1 cada um dos seguintes inputs,até aqui tudo bem, mas caso tenha inserido 10 pagamentos e a partir da quinta parcela ele tenha dado uma sequencia de cheques de outro talão que não é sequencial ao talão anterior, preciso que ao inserir o número do cheque ele incremente em +1 a  partir deste input exemplo abaixo:

> cheques talão 1 inicia na folha 2034 e termina na folha 2038

```
parcela 1: 2034
parcela 2: 2035
parcela 3: 2036
parcela 4: 2037
parcela 5: 2038
```

> cheque talão 2 que inicia com a folha número 7332

```
parcela 6: 7332
parcela 7: 7333
parcela 8: 7334
parcela 9: 7335
parcela 10: 7336
```

Mas o que está acontecendo de fato é ao inserir um novo valor na posição 5 ele incrementa de forma errada, e o blur também interfere nos valores mesmo que não o tenha alterado. Qual a forma de contornar está falha, ou devo mudar toda a estrutura?

```js
$(document).on('blur', '.ncheque', function() {
  var chqs = $('.ncheque');
  var index = null;
  var partes = this.value.split('-');
  var valor = parseInt(partes[1] || partes[0]);
  indice = chqs.index(this);
  if (valor) {
    $('.ncheque').each(function(index) {
      if (index > indice) {
        $(this).val([partes[1] ? partes[0] : null, valor + index].filter(Boolean).join('-'));
      }
    });
  } else {
    $('.ncheque').val('');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="ncheque"><br>
<input type="text" class="ncheque"><br>
<input type="text" class="ncheque"><br>
<input type="text" class="ncheque"><br>
<input type="text" class="ncheque"><br>
<input type="text" class="ncheque"><br>
<input type="text" class="ncheque"><br>
```

Comment: Esse `split('-')` seria oq? O valor pode ter hífen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma forma mais simplificada de fazer isso em comparação ao seu código. Ao alterar o valor de um `input`, apenas os seguintes serão modificados incrementando `+1` ao valor do `input` alterado.

```js
$(document).on('blur', '.ncheque', function() {
   var chqs = $('.ncheque');
   var qtd = chqs.length; // quantidade de inputs
   var indice = chqs.index(this); // pega o índice do input blur
   for(var x=indice; x<qtd; x++){
      chqs[x+1] ? chqs[x+1].value = parseInt(chqs[x].value)+1 : null; // incrementa os seguintes até o final
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="ncheque"><br>
<input type="text" class="ncheque"><br>
<input type="text" class="ncheque"><br>
<input type="text" class="ncheque"><br>
<input type="text" class="ncheque"><br>
<input type="text" class="ncheque"><br>
<input type="text" class="ncheque"><br>
```

Comment: Ficou até mais rápido usando desta forma, obrigado.